# ng-template content do not get rendered inside the title attribute with bootstrap tooltip in Angular

Tags: angular, user-interface, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I need to display a custom tooltip over a button and I use Bootstrap v4 for this in my Angular project.

The HTML content I define in my ng-template does not get rendered and what I see as the tooltip when hovered over the button is `[object Object]`

[image]

This is the bootstrap documentation for tooltip: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/
But, the HTML tags are not rendered as the documentation says.

Therefore, I tried the approach mentioned in this article and the code(+stackblitz) is given below.
https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-ng-bootstrap-tooltip-tutorial/

**app.component.html**

```
<ng-template  #tipContent >
  <div >
    <table>
      <tr >
        <td >Current Value</td>                                       
      </tr>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let d of dataArray">
          <td>{{d.value}} </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  
    </table>
  </div>
</ng-template>



<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"   data-html="true"  [title]="tipContent">
  Tooltip on bottom
</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  dataArray: any[]=[
  {
    value:'Val 1'
  },
  {
    value:'Val 2'
  },
  {
    value:'Val 3'
  }
  ];

  

  // Method to return a toltip string
  getCustomToolTip() {
    let items = ''
  
    for(let ob of this.dataArray) {
       items = items + '<tr><td>' + ob.value + '</td></tr>'
    }
      let tooltip = `<table>
      <thead>
                            <tr >
    
                              <th>Current Value</th>
                                                 
                            </tr>
    
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            ${items}
                          </tbody>
    
                        </table>`
    
    return tooltip;
                  
  }

}
```

**For Stackblitz code, click [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-include-6dx1vs?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: I think [title] is expecting text, but you’re giving it an object, so it’s converting it to text and displaying [object Object]

Comment: I passed getCustomToolTip() method to [title] as it returns a text. But, it does not render the HTML text and shows the whole raw text as the tooltip

Comment: That’s because it’s expecting plain text, not HTML. I think you need to use another method to achieve your goal, though I don’t know what that is.

Comment: In bootstrap documentation, it says that we can use HTML tags inside the title but they are not actually rendered.  Therefore I tried out this method which has been used in other bootstrap libraries.

Comment: Your use of [title] is an Angular convention, though. Can you link to the documentation you’re referring to?

Comment: This is the bootstrap documentation for tooltip: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/ But, the HTML tags are not rendered as the documentation says.

Therefore, I tried the approach mentioned in this article even if it is for ng-bootstrap. https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-ng-bootstrap-tooltip-tutorial/

Comment: The tutorial says that you should be setting the ngbcontent property to your tooltip, but your setting the title property.